# Streaming video to a <video> tag

Tags: camera, streaming-video, raspivid

I have the Raspberry camera module, and I try to get the following setup to stream live video to a website:

Html code:

```
 <video width="640" height="480" controls autoplay>
     <source src="stream.node" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
```

Then, I use `raspivid` to stream to that node:

```
raspivid -t 999999 -o stream.node -w 640 -h 480
```

the `stream.node` is a named pipe:

```
$ ls -la
prw-r--r-- 1 pi pi      0 May  2 05:06 stream.node
```

The problem is, `raspivids` exits as soon as the browser opens the page with the `video` tag in it.

I see many solutions using all kinds of extra software, but I reckoned this should work as well. But apparently not. Am I missing something, or on a complete wrong path (if so, why?).

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? I am using gstreamer myself and I went a little further ahead but I am not yet able to see a video in the browser: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/66228/streaming-to-a-video-tag-with-the-hardware-encoder

Comment: Nope, nothing yet.